# Can a thread-safe class contain any public instance fields?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Can a thread-safe class contain any **public** instance fields?

Comment: Sure, why not? Thread safety is not exactly a formal concept, anyway. Your question is much too general and vague.

Comment: Show the audience your code, and we'll see if it's thread-safe or not. Without code noone say in general if it's "thread-safe" or not - it depends on the implementation and usage.

Answer (score 1):

Access modifieres are irrelevant in this context of thread-safety.  Of course you can have public fields in a thread safe class, the question you need to ask yourself is : Does this conform to my / a design pattern and what could I possibly achieve from doing this.

Comment: no, its **not irrelevant**. If you only have private immutable members, all methods being called from all threads will see these members in the same state. If any member is either mutable (e.g. a mutable `List`) or the access to it is public, you can never be sure if these values change while you're working on them. Best example is a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 1):

When people say that class C is "thread-safe", they usually mean that no interleaving of operations performed on a single instance of the class by multiple threads can leave the instance in an invalid state. (But as Marko says, that's not a formally agreed-upon definition.) So, what are the states of an instance of your class? Which states are valid and which are not valid? Is it possible to change a valid state into an invalid state by updating one of the public fields?

If there is any way that updating a public field can change the state from valid to invalid, then you can't say that the class is *generally* thread safe, but if that never happens in your application, then maybe the class is thread-safe *in the limited context of your application.*